# Client-Server application do nothing when trying to get response from server C#/

Tags: c#, client, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm writing client-server application. Client sending command and server recieves it and do some manipulations. It works well. But when i'm trying to send response from server to client and recieve it on client side nothing happens. Even server do nothing. Program hangs and only Shift+F5 helps to finish it.

Server code:

```
class TNPClient
{
    TNPBaseInterraction tnp_base;

    private void SendError(TcpClient Client, int Code)
    {
        byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Code.ToString());
        Client.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        Client.Close();
    }

    private void SendResponse(TcpClient Client, string response)
    {
        byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
        Client.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        Client.Close();
    }

    void ParseMonitorRequest(TcpClient Client, string req)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("inside parser");
        int term_id = Convert.ToInt32(req.Substring(2));
        switch (req[1])
        {
            case '0':
                List<MonitorStruct> monitors = tnp_base.GetMonitors(term_id);
                foreach (MonitorStruct mon in monitors)
                {

                }
                break;
            case '1':
                break;
            case '2':
                break;
            case '3':
                break;
            case '4':
                MessageBox.Show("inside 4");
                List<TerminalStruct> terminals = tnp_base.GetTerminals();
                foreach (TerminalStruct term in terminals)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("sending response");
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ID: {0} Address: {1} Comment: {2}", term.TerminalID, term.Address, term.Comment));
                    //SendResponse(Client, string.Format("ID: {0} Address: {1} Comment: {2}", term.TerminalID, term.Address, term.Comment));
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    void ParseTerminalRequest(TcpClient Client, string req)
    {

    }

    public TNPClient(TcpClient Client)
    {
        try
        {
            tnp_base = new TNPBaseInterraction("127.0.0.1", "tnp", "tnp_user", "tnp123", "3406");

            string Request = "";
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int Count = 0;
            while ((Count = Client.GetStream().Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Request += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, Count);
            }
            if (Request[0].Equals('0'))
            {
                ParseMonitorRequest(Client, Request);
            }
            else
            {
                ParseTerminalRequest(Client, Request);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

class TNPServer
{
    TcpListener Listener;
    int Port = 5252;

    public TNPServer(int ServerPort)
    {
        int MaxThreadsCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 4;
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxThreadsCount, MaxThreadsCount);
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 2);

        Port = ServerPort;
    }

    public void StartServer()
    {
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        Listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ClientThread), Listener.AcceptTcpClient());
        }
    }

    static void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)
    {
        new TNPClient((TcpClient)StateInfo);
    }

    ~TNPServer()
    {
        if (Listener != null)
        {
            Listener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Client side code (this code gives problem):

```
try
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5365);
    if (client.Connected) MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tbSendText.Text);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
   // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    //client.ReceiveTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int Count = 0;
    string response = string.Empty;
  //  while ((Count = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    //{
        Count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, Count);
    //}

        stream.Close();
    client.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(response);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

All messages on server side are shown then i'm not trying to get response on client side. When i'm trying to get response no messages are shown, but connection is established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server side, the read loop is blocked forever. You need to read only up to to the length of the text & then parse the request. You can write the length of the text from client side & then write the content.